# When will Gnu C++ support C++11 without explicitly asking for it?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, gcc4.8

Currently, with g++-4.8.1 you have to compile a file in C++11-mode via

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o prog.x prog.cpp
```

Is there a plan when I just can say

```
g++ -o prog.x prog.cpp
```

to compile `prog.cpp`?

Maybe `prog.cpp` has

- `#include <regex>`
- `thread_local`
- `class Widget { int member = 5; }`
- `MyType operator"" myt(const char*, sze_t);`
- and so on.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is directed at the GNU C Compiler project.

Comment: Not for 4.9 at least. Maybe 4.10 (or 5.0), maybe later.

Comment: Defaulting to C++11 could potentially break some existing code. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11) lists some of the changes that could cause a problem.

Comment: I use 4.8.1 and I compile directly without having to pass `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @mebob I know. But the standardizers ver extra super special careful to make the incompatibilities visible at recompile.

Comment: @BSH Then I gather you are not using any C++11 features

Comment: @towi I just compiled a code with lambda and auto, compiled fine.

Comment: @towi Good point. I was just mentioning since it could be a little bit of a bother if you are trying to compile an existing project without being aware the compiler would default to the C++11 standard. Obviously, it would be an easy fix: `-std=c++03` for GCC.

Comment: Probably right after they did something similar to the C compiler...

Comment: Related: [Why C++11 compiler support still requires a flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373626/why-c11-compiler-support-still-requires-a-flag) Might even be a duplicate.

Comment: @mebob To be honest, when I scroll through the list I don't expect there is much bother with 99.998% projects. That's what they aimed for. The `auto` may be an issue with very oldish C/C++-code but the rest will be esoteric stuff and easy to fix -- the compiler will complain about most (`int final = 12`. Oh, wait, actually, that will compile, too, I think -- it's a context-keyword, isn't it?).

Comment: @remyabel Oh, indeed. My question is Gnu C++-specific. But your point is well taken. The answer to that question is a bit more general, though.

Comment: IMO the difference between this question and others is that others are asking why and this is asking when. Therefore I think it's off-topic because it boils down to speculation.

Comment: @remyabel ...or knowledge because it might have been discussed by the gnu c++ team. Thus, I do 'not complain too loudly if you decide its either. Although: For many questions here at SO you could just "write an Email to the authors" ;-)

Comment: Quite agree with @mfukar. This is a good fit for [magic 8-ball](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1696/238706). :-)

Comment: @Palec You may be right. I leave the question closed, because it has been answered satisfactory for me. The correct Ouya-board-autocorrect would have been "Should my teaching slides for C++ students contain that they always have to add some special flag to the (gnu-)compiler or should I deliver that remark in the verbal channel only?"

Comment: For long term maintainability you should *always* specify the language standard. This way your coders won't accidentally use a C++14 feature. Moving to a new standard becomes a conscious choice and you don't go back to compile on RHEL 6 and only then discover you need to rewrite big chunks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

GCC 6.0: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html

> The default mode for C++ is now `-std=gnu++14` instead of `-std=gnu++98`.

Answer (score 20):

The closest I think to an answer I can get is from the `info gcc` command:

> A revised ISO C++ standard was published in 2011 as ISO/IEC
>   14882:2011, and is referred to as C++11; before its publication it was
>   commonly referred to as C++0x.  C++11 contains several changes to the
>   C++ language, most of which have been implemented in an experimental
>   C++11 mode in GCC.  For information regarding the C++11 features
>   available in the experimental C++11 mode, see
>   http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html.  To select this standard in
>   GCC, use the option '-std=c++11'; to obtain all the diagnostics
>   required by the standard, you should also specify '-pedantic' (or
>   '-pedantic-errors' if you want them to be errors rather than
>   warnings).

The http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html page says:

> Important: GCC's support for C++11 is still experimental. Some
>   features were implemented based on early proposals, and no attempt
>   will be made to maintain backward compatibility when they are updated
>   to match the final C++11 standard.

The [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) page also shows that it is incomplete. (I don't even think `regex` is implemented yet.)

[Steve Jessop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20373913/1508519) basically says the same thing in the last paragraph, but to quote the first part of his answer:

> C++11 has been standard for a couple of years, but a compiler isn't
>   going to switch its default mode to C++11 until:
>
> - At an absolute minimum, C++11 support is complete in that compiler and the libraries it uses. And also stable, if the compiler
>     writer has any concern at all for reliability.
> - Preferably, a major version number increase in the compiler, since C++11 is not fully backward-compatible to C++03.
> - Ideally, on a well-known schedule so that users can prepare for the change.

Comment: Regex is implemented in 4.9. The notion of "complete" support is vague. If they wait for bugzilla to be empty, they will never switch.

Comment: The same contents as in `info gcc` is available in online docs (page [Standards](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html)). For current status, see [C Dialect Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) – for C it states under gnu11: “GNU dialect of ISO C11. This is intended to become the default in a future release of GCC.” But for gnu++11 nor any other C++ dialect, there is no such remark. BTW probably gnu++11 will be a default sometime, not c++11.

Comment: @Marc Yep, it is implemented in the snapshot of gcc I have, but gcc 4.9 isn't released yet.

Comment: @MarcGlisse while it's missing classes, functions and entire header files, it's not "complete" by any measure.

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE:** The original answer has become outdated in the past 28 months. According to [nobar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33239133/341970), GCC 6.1 supports C++14 with GNU extensions by default. GCC 6.1 was  released on April 27, 2016. I am quite surprised but very happy to see such a fast adoption of the new standard!

As for the rest of the original answer, I still see value in keeping that part that answers how to make certain flags "default". So I kept it below.

---

> Is there a plan when I just can say [...]

You could define default flags in a Makefile and then all you have to say is `make`.

The accepted answer to [How do I enable C++11 in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16886591/341970) should get you started (or  some [makefile tutorial](https://www.google.com/#q=makefile+tutorial)).

Another advice that seems to pop up often here at Stackoverflow is to add a bash alias `alias g++="g++ --std=c++0x"`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17379141/341970) how. However, I personally wouldn't do this though, it can lead to unpleasant surprises; there has been breaking changes with C++11. I would create my own makefile and type simply `make`.

---

Comment: Anonymous downvotes aren't helping anybody. What's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score -3):

It seems GCC 5.0 will have gnu11 (dialect of c++11 AFAIK) by default with improvements to c++11 as being shared in changes. See https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html . It seems it will have some support for C++14 as well.

One of the more interesting statements as far as regards to the bugzilla scenario as shared by @marc-glisse seems to be off the table, see https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/criteria.html for details :-

> All regressions open in Bugzilla have been analyzed, and all are
>   deemed as either unlikely to affect most users, or are determined to
>   have a minimal impact on affected users. For example, a typographical
>   error in a diagnostic might be relatively common, but also has minimal
>   impact on users.
>
> In general, regressions where the compiler generates incorrect code,
>   or refuses to compile a valid program, will be considered to be
>   sufficiently severe to block the release, unless there are substantial
>   mitigating factors. - GCC release criteria page

The timeline does give some idea as to when and if it will happen https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#timeline

So hopefully we should see a new gcc with c++11 support as default by 2015. When will GNU/Linux distributions take up and do whatever they need to do for softwares being built with c++11 is another question altogether.

Comment: I did read it before. It's just that I just don't know what the differences between gnu11 and c++11 are or would be and haven't been able to find much about the differences between the two as of now . The idea is that it should become as a default in near future.

Comment: gnu11 refers to the C language dialect, not C++.

Comment: ohk, my mistake then.

Comment: gnu11 -> c11, gnu++11 -> c++11