# Reading from file using as parameter char*

Tags: c++, char

I am using a function that uses a char* parameter; i am reading from a file for input. Here is my code:

```
std::ifstream infile("file.txt");
std::string line;
while(std::getline(infile,line)){
    if(pass(line.c_str())==0) cout<<"this is correct"<<line<<endl;
}
```

the pass function is

```
int pass(char* a);
//compares c_string to hidden c_string
//if the same then return 0, else retuns -1
```

I am compiling using g++ -c 6.cpp and the error is:

invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

initializing argument 1 of 'int pass(char*)

Comment: `line.c_str()` returns a `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
int pass(const char* a);
```

Comment: the pass function is not changeable. From instructor.

Comment: In that case allocate another string and copy contents to this new string. Then pass it into the function.

Comment: so, string k =line; then pass(k);?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char

Answer (score 0):

When you are converting `std::string`, `c_str()` returs a `const char*` rather than `char*`, so you must redefine the function to `int pass(const char*);`.

if you are looking to convert `std::string` directly to `char*`,

```
const char *ptr = str.c_str() ;
char *new_str = new char[str.size()+1];  //+1 for null ending char
strcpy(new_str, str.c_str());
```

this copies the contents of `str` into the `char*` array `new_str`.

Comment: `strcpy()` stops copying on the first null character. If the `std::string` contains embedded nulls, use `strncpy(new_str, str.c_str(), str.size())` instead, or even `memcpy(new_str, str.c_str(), str.size()+1)` or `std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), new_str)`.

Comment: `strncpy` also stops on embedded nulls (and even if it didn't, the size should be `str.size()+1`)

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

```
if ( !line.empty() && pass(&line[0]) )
     cout << "this is correct" << line <<endl;
```

You have to check `empty` as `line[0]` only works if there is a character in it.

If you are sure that `pass` does not try to write to the string, you can also go:

```
pass( const_cast<char *>(line.c_str()) );
```

Comment: `line[0]` on an empty string is guaranteed to return a reference to a `\0` character.

Comment: @Quentin I'm not sure if that was true before C++11 (OP's compilation command shows C++03 mode)

Comment: A-ha, [not since GCC 6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33239133/3233393)! Just kidding, [you're right](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at), I had forgotten that it wasn't the case in C++03.