# C++ convert int to string inline

Tags: c++, string, data-conversion

My problem seems to be very basic but I could not find a solution for it. I need to write a code which helps debugging by reporting the line and location of exception throwing. The problem is that `__LINE__` is an `int` value and I have problem with its conversion into string in the following code where `std::string(line)` is used:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>


class CRuntime_error_line: public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    CRuntime_error_line(const char * msg, const char * file,int line)
        :runtime_error(std::string(msg)+" @"+":"+std::string(line)){}
};

#define runtime_error_line(msg) CRuntime_error_line(msg,__FILE__,__LINE__)
```

Seems `std::string(line)` cannot convert int to string and other solutions suggested online cannot be implemented inline and I don't know how to call a base constructor in second line!

compiler output:

> log.h: In constructor ‘CRuntime_error_line::CRuntime_error_line(const
>   char*, const char*, int)’: log.h:10:124: error: invalid conversion
>   from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive] CRuntime_error_line(const
>   char * msg, const char * file,int
>   line):runtime_error(std::string(msg)+" @"+":"+std::string(line)){}

(Using g++ and linux environment)

**edit:**

the macro is supposed to be called this way:

```
throw runtime_error_line("Invalid somethihng ...!");
```

Comment: [`std::to_string(line)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: error: `‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’`

Comment: `to_string` should work. http://ideone.com/5qc3GN

Comment: including <string> makes no change. `error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’`. Does C++11 applies to my codes?

Comment: @barej Yes, `to_string` is from C++11

Comment: @barej What version of g++ are you using? (g++ -v)

Comment: `gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)`

Comment: @barej You have to explicitly [enable C++11 support](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21221411/2642059): g++ -std=c++11 -o prog.x prog.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is suggested by [Borgleader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583833/borgleader) `std::to_string` is your solution. It will also construct a temporary `std::string` for you, so there's no need to construct a temporary string from `msg`:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <string> // Add this to support std::to_string


class CRuntime_error_line: public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    CRuntime_error_line(const char* msg, const char* file, int line)
        : runtime_error(msg + " @:"s + std::to_string(line)){} // Use std::to_string here
};

#define runtime_error_line(msg) CRuntime_error_line(msg, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Without C++11 you can still do this it's just not as clean:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream> // Use to include std::ostringstream    

class CRuntime_error_line: public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    CRuntime_error_line(const char* msg, const char* file, int line)
        : runtime_error(static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << msg << " @:" << line).str()){} // Use std::ostringstream here
};

#define runtime_error_line(msg) CRuntime_error_line(msg, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Comment: seems g++ compiler does not recognize `std::to_string` for me!

Comment: `log.h: In constructor ‘CRuntime_error_line::CRuntime_error_line(const char*, const char*, int)’:
log.h:12:40: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
         : runtime_error(msg + (" @:" + std::to_string(line))){} // Use std::to_string here
  `

Comment: have u added : --std=c++11 ?

Comment: the code compiles but there is something wrong with the output: `0x401938 @:47`. it is not what i expect to see!

Comment: Thank you very much, please add ` g++ -std=c++11 -o prog.x prog.cpp ` to the end of your solution for others with the similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

int this case may be better :

```
#define STRING_DEFINE1(x) #x
#define STRING_DEFINE(x) STRING_DEFINE1(x)
...
CRuntime_error_line(msg,__FILE__,STRING_DEFINE(__LINE__))
```

Comment: creative idea, even though for limited applications.

Comment: Or better define RUNTIME_ERROR_MAGIC which is `__FILE__ " " STRING_DEFINE(__LINE__)` and then you have a single string literal to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing I can think of would be to write a `to_string` yourself:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string to_string(int i)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << i;
    return os.str();
}
```

Then call it as others have suggested.