# Compilation Error: "‘function’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type"

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm trying to sniff my network traffic using [*libtins*](http://libtins.github.io/download/) library. So I downloaded the *tar.gz* library and I finished all the library compilation steps mentioned in the manual one by one successfully.

Now, I'm trying to compile my first sample program:

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <tins/tins.h>
  3 
  4 using namespace Tins;
  5 
  6 bool callback(const PDU &pdu) {
  7     const IP &ip = pdu.rfind_pdu<IP>(); // Find the IP layer
  8     const TCP &tcp = pdu.rfind_pdu<TCP>(); // Find the TCP layer
  9     std::cout << ip.src_addr() << ':' << tcp.sport() << " -> "
 10               << ip.dst_addr() << ':' << tcp.dport() << std::endl;
 11     return true;
 12 }
 13 
 14 int main() {
 15     Sniffer("eth0").sniff_loop(callback);
 16 }
```

When I want to compile it, I face the following errors:

```
me@me-MS-7693:~/Desktop/Workspace/cpp_libtins$ g++ main.cpp -ltins
In file included from /usr/local/include/tins/tins.h:60:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:297:18: error: ‘function’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     typedef std::function<void(const std::string&,
                  ^
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:308:18: error: ‘function’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     typedef std::function<void(const std::string&,
                  ^
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:401:44: error: ‘handshake_captured_callback_type’ does not name a type
     void handshake_captured_callback(const handshake_captured_callback_type& callback);
                                            ^
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:412:34: error: ‘ap_found_callback_type’ does not name a type
     void ap_found_callback(const ap_found_callback_type& callback);
                                  ^
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:445:9: error: ‘handshake_captured_callback_type’ does not name a type
         handshake_captured_callback_type handshake_captured_callback_;
         ^
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:446:9: error: ‘ap_found_callback_type’ does not name a type
         ap_found_callback_type ap_found_callback_;
         ^
me@me-MS-7693:~/Desktop/Workspace/cpp_libtins$
```

What is wrong?

---

My compiler version:

```
me@me-MS-7693:~/Desktop/Workspace/cpp_libtins$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

me@me-MS-7693:~/Desktop/Workspace/cpp_libtins$
```

Comment: Are you misssing the `-std=c++11` flag? What's your GCC version?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Trying with `-std=c++11` solved the issue. But what's going on? Why?

Comment: @DieterLücking: https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins/blob/master/include/tins/crypto.h

Comment: @Abraham: You didn't read your compiler's documentation, did you? Your compiler version runs in C++03 mode by default.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Where can I see this documentation? Is it in `man g++` result?

Comment: @Abraham: https://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: Yes, it's in `man g++`, see "gnu++98 gnu++03: GNU dialect of -std=c++98.  This is the default for C++ code."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your GCC is older than 6.0, you need to pass the `-std=c++11` switch, [otherwise it is in C++03 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33239133/560648). C++03 did not have `std::function`.