# unordered_set in Cython using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cython

I'm stuck trying to use unordered_sets in Cython in a Jupyter Notebook on my Mac.

```
%%cython -a -3
# distutils: language = c++
# cython: c_string_type=unicode, c_string_encoding=utf8
import cython
from libcpp.unordered_set cimport unordered_set

def test():
    cdef unordered_set[int] s
    return s
```

The above cell throws: 
`DistutilsExecError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: If you look at the terminal window you started jupyter from, the gcc output should be there?  FWIW this works fine on Windows with Visual C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked for me was a modified version of [@ead's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030581/3915498).

I [updated GCC using homebrew](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8336714) (and XCode), and the following code does not throw the same error as before.

```
%%cython -a -3 -c=-stdlib=libc++
# distutils: language = c++

import cython
from libcpp.unordered_set cimport unordered_set

def test():
    cdef unordered_set[int] s
    return s
```

Answer (score 2):

Older gcc versions don't use c++-11 (but c++-98) per default, and because `unordered_map` is a c++11-feature, you need to pass the option to the compiler.

For example via:

```
%%cython -a -3 -c=-std=c++11
```

Or update your gcc to [6.0 or above.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33239133/5769463)

Comment: Thanks! I had to pass `-c=-stdlib=libc++` to make it work on OSX.